# Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following

Tags: plsql, oracle12c

I am encountering the following error when defining a function.
"Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following:..."
I am trying this example from a website. I also wanted to understand the cursors logic used here.

> 1. Can we fetch values from and close the cursor in definition part?
> 2. What is the significance of c1%notfound block and assigning a high value 9999 to p_cid?

```
create or replace function get_cust_id(p_cname IN varchar2)
RETURN number
IS
p_cid number;

cursor c1 is
select p_cid from customers where c_name = p_cname;

BEGIN

OPEN c1;
FETCH c1 INTO into p_cid;

if c1%notfound
then
p_cid:=9999;
end if;

close c1;

RETURN p_cid;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

============================================

The above "INTO" problem was rectified because of typo error.

I am now trying to call the function, but the output is not as expected :

```
select c_name,get_cust_id(c_name) as cust_id
from customers
where city='London';
```

Output :

```
C_NAME  CUST_ID
Alice    - 
Patrick  -
```

Comment: `FETCH c1 INTO into p_cid;` **2x `INTO`** Remove one of them

Comment: Thank you for your observation. It worked!

Comment: By the way, `sqlcode` is just the error number that is already included within `sqlerrm`, for example if `sqlerrm` is *'ORA-01234: Bananas are not available on a Tuesday'* then `sqlcode` is -1234 and `SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM` gives *-1234 -ERROR- ORA-01234: Bananas are not available on a Tuesday*. What is the point of that? (Edit: just noticed your comment *I am trying this example from a website.* I don't think it's a great website.)

Comment: Okay I now understand the difference between `sqlcode` and `sqlerrm`. Thank you very much for your input! It would be of great help if you could recommend me a few websites that would help me build strong logic in plsql.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the double `into` that @Lukasz pointed out in comments, your cursor query is doing this:

```
select p_cid from customers where c_name = p_cname;
```

The `p_cid` here is the number you just declared, which hasn't been assigned a value yet. So you're effectively doing:

```
select null from customers where c_name = p_cname;
```

which is why your test query gets nulls back from the function calls. You need to change `p_cid` in that query to the column name in the table, which I'd guess is either just `id` or `c_id`:

```
create or replace function get_cust_id(p_cname IN varchar2)
RETURN number
IS
p_cid number;

cursor c1 is
select c_id from customers where c_name = p_cname;

BEGIN

OPEN c1;
FETCH c1 INTO p_cid;
...
```

> Can we fetch values from and close the cursor in definition part?

No.

> What is the significance of c1%notfound block and assigning a high value 9999 to p_cid?

If you pass in a name that does not exist (which can't happen the way you are calling it, but it's very contrived anyway) then the cursor query will find no data for that name. The `fetch` will not throw an error, but will not actually retrieve anything. [The %notfound` cursor attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-BC2BA7E6-EFCE-4105-8305-807074F8B6A5) is true, because no row was fetched.

In that situation, the `if c1%notfound` is true so the `p_cid:=9999;` statement is executed, and that value is later returned to the caller.

Effectively it's returning 9999 as a 'magic number' indicating that there was no actual ID found. (It would probably be safer to either return null, or throw an exception, if that happened - magic numbers can cause problems later, e.g. - fairly obviously - if you also have a real customer with ID 9999...)

There are simpler ways to achieve what this function is doing, but presumably it's trying to teach you specific things, in its contrived way.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I understood the concept of using 9999. I will try return null and throw exceptions in my next codes. I would also like to know what value should be passed to the function, such that WHEN OTHERS THEN block gets executed?

Comment: Well, the `when others then` pattern is usually not a good idea, and it would be simpler to exclude it and just let the original exception bubble up to the caller. I'm not sure you can manufacture a way to get an exception - you won't get no-data-found or too-many-rows (if `c_id` is not unique) because of the cursor logic. If `c_id` was a string column then you could get ORA-01722 from a non-numeric string value; but that would be even more contrived.

Comment: Thank you for your input! The <when others then> block is not apt in this code.

Answer (score 0):

The output was as expected when I changed the following line :

```
select c_id into p_cid from customers where c_name = p_cname;
```

Output :

```
C_NAME  CUST_ID
Alice   3
Patrick 6
```